# Exporting ray-traced 3D animation Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, animation, image-trace

I have a 3D logo made in photoshop and I made a basic 3D rotation animation.
I ray-trace the object but when I export it, it appears that it's not ray-traced and looks bad. I've tried all the 3D options in video export menu with no luck.

[image: How it looks in photoshop - ray traced]

[image: Exported video]

Comment: what file format are you exporting to? This looks like a low-color GIF.

Comment: I am exporting it as a Quicktime High quality animation with Alpha channel. I also tried without alpha channel same results. Is this suppose to happen? Even if I choose Ray Trace Final option this is what I get.